# Diazo - replace css attributes

Tags: plone, diazo

I am trying to replace some CSS styles using the Diazo `replace` and `attributes` rules, but so far I have not been able to figure it out.

So far I have been success in using the Diazo `replace`,`copy`, `before`,`after`,`drop` rules for `css:content`,`css:theme`,`css:content-children`,and `css:theme-children`.

My current markup is based off Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 and is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-md--8 well">
            <p>Plone content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the `drop` rule I can remove the class from my `#content`:

```
<drop attributes="class" css:theme="#theme"/>
```

But I can not figure out how to add the css class `col-12` in. The `col-12` does not exist anywhere in my theme. I have tried the following rules so far:

```
<replace attributes="class col-12" css:theme="#theme"/>
<replace attributes="col-12" css:theme="#theme"/>
```

I do have an example of a `copy` rule where the `href` link is copied from the Plone `#portal-logo`:

```
<copy attributes="href" css:content="#portal-logo" css:theme="#logo" />
```

I feel like I am close, and all I need is a similar example. I have been looking at the Diazo docs for [Basic syntax](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/basic.html) but haven't been able to figure this one out yet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and if I figure this out before I get a response I will update my question

Thanks.

Comment: Does http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/diazo/recipes/adding-an-attribute/index.html help?

Answer (score 6):

usually I use this rule to "map" the sunburst grid into bootstrap(2):

```
<replace content="//div[contains(@class,'cell')]/@class">
<xsl:attribute name="class">
<xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-3:4")'>span9</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-2:3")'>span8</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-1:2")'>span6</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-1:3")'>span4</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-1:4")'>span3</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-full")'>span12</xsl:if>
</xsl:attribute>
</replace>
```

Hope this help.

Vito

Answer (score 0):

I have used syntax like:

```
<replace content="//div[@class='row']">
    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="."/> col-12</xsl:attribute>
</replace>
```

to add classes to elements.

This one should add the class `col-12` (and keep existing `row` class) to all `div`s that has `row` as class in the content.